# Pushing text to an array in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to push some text to an array using Redux but am getting stuck. After I make a copy of my state I'm not exactly sure what to do. Also, just want to confirm that I should be importing my `appState` into my reducer.

store.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

export const appState = {
    links: []
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, appState);

export default store;
```

reducers/index.js

```
import {appState} from '../store';

function addLink(state = appState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_LINK': 
            const linkName = action.linkName;
            console.log('Adding link');
            console.log(linkName);
            console.log(appState);
            return {
                ...state.splice(),
                // Now what?

            };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

export default addLink;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to import `appState`. Assuming state is just an array, your method should be as below.

```
function addLink(state = {links: []}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_LINK': 
            const linkName = action.linkName;
            console.log('Adding link');
            console.log(linkName);
            console.log(appState);
            return {
               ...state,
               links: [linkName, ...state.links]
            };
         default: 
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But it's not updating my store state. `links` is still an empty array :(

Comment: You need to inject your store at the top of your DOM. `<Provider store={store}></Provider>` Something like this.

Comment: @staxwell I updated the code. Try it. your initial state wasn't matching the operation you asked for.